# Помогите понять код tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def onMove(value):
    print('in onMove', value)

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
Scale(root, label='Scale', command=onMove,
      variable=var, from_=0, to=4, length=200, tickinterval=1,
      orient='horizontal').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Не понимаю, как передается аргумент `value` в функцию onMove(), если мы не передаем его явно из command=onMove и он не указан в глобальной области видимости. Откуда функция обработчик onMove() получает значение аргумента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виджет `Scale` предоставляет объект графического ползунка,
который позволяет вам выбирать значения из определенной шкалы.

Синтаксис для создания этого виджета:

```
w = Scale ( master, option, ... )
```

- **command** - Процедура, вызываемая каждый раз при перемещении ползунка.
  ***Этой процедуре будет передан один аргумент - новое значение шкалы***.
  Если ползунок перемещается быстро, вы можете не получить обратный вызов для
  каждой возможной позиции, но вы обязательно получите обратный вызов, когда он установится.
- **variable** - Управляющая переменная для этой шкалы, если есть.
  Управляющие переменные могут быть из класса IntVar, DoubleVar (float) или StringVar.
  В последнем случае числовое значение будет преобразовано в строку.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько помню `command=onMove` передает значение в указанную функцию.
То есть где-то в недрах функции Scale выполняется код onMove(1), где число = текущее положение ползунка.